# Supplying query parameters to Google Sheets "feeds" URL fails to filter sheet data

Tags: google-sheets-api

I want to get json data from spreadsheet (with filtering), but it seems when I use a structured query (by adding `tq` into my link), the filter is ignored.

For example, this link

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1xeVDIWxVZrkiUjSE1xX9xW--pEm93IL4BH3L1jmS_4A/1/public/values?alt=json&tq=select%20*%20where%20nama=test1
```

should filter the spreadsheet data by "SELECT * where nama=test1"

However, the received data is like this:

```
entry": [
  {
    "id": {
        "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1xeVDIWxVZrkiUjSE1xX9xW--pEm93IL4BH3L1jmS_4A/1/public/values/cokwr"
    },
    "updated": {
        "$t": "2018-05-06T14:42:16.881Z"
    },
    "category": [{
        "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
        "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
    }],
    "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "$t": "test1"
    },
    "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "$t": "password: pass1, userid: 123"
    },
    "link": [{
        "rel": "self",
        "type": "application/atom+xml",
        "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1xeVDIWxVZrkiUjSE1xX9xW--pEm93IL4BH3L1jmS_4A/1/public/values/cokwr"
    }],
    "gsx$nama": { "$t": "test1" },
    "gsx$password": { "$t": "pass1" },
    "gsx$userid": { "$t": "123" }
  },
  {
    "id": {
        "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1xeVDIWxVZrkiUjSE1xX9xW--pEm93IL4BH3L1jmS_4A/1/public/values/cpzh4"
    },
    "updated": {
        "$t": "2018-05-06T14:42:16.881Z"
    },
    "category": [{
            "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
            "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
    }],
    "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "$t": "test2"
    },
    "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "$t": "password: pass2, userid: 456"
    },
    "link": [{
        "rel": "self",
        "type": "application/atom+xml",
        "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1xeVDIWxVZrkiUjSE1xX9xW--pEm93IL4BH3L1jmS_4A/1/public/values/cpzh4"
    }],
    "gsx$nama": { "$t": "test2" },
    "gsx$password": { "$t": "pass2" },
    "gsx$userid": { "$t": "456" }
  }
]
```

I.e., it's not filtered and gives the entire data from the spreadsheet. I don't know if the error is on query param. How can I perform this filtering via URL querying?

Comment: How about this? ``https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xeVDIWxVZrkiUjSE1xX9xW--pEm93IL4BH3L1jmS_4A/gviz/tq?gid=0&tq=SELECT%20%2a%20WHERE%20A%3d%27test1%27`` I used ``SELECT * WHERE A='test1'`` for this as a sample. When users access to this URL, a json file is downloaded.

Comment: ya this is worked as i expected but i not need the json file downloaded. just stream in google api spreadsheet like my link. thank you so much, is very helpfull @Tanaike

Comment: When you access to URL using your browser, a JSON file is downloaded. But for example, when you access to URL using curl and urlfetch, the JSON data is retrieved. If you had already tried this, I'm sorry.

Comment: ya i have tried it, thank you very much its realy helpfull

Comment: Welcome. If your issue was solved, I'm glad.